# Why is WGAN considered an adversarial network?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I finished going over the WGAN paper: [WGAN Paper Link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07875.pdf)

After reading the algorithm provided by the writers I find it odd that they would refer to the network as an adversarial network.
In the first part of the algorithm a 'critic' is trained to optimality and they show this critic approximates the Wasserstein distance between our generator distribution and the real distribution. We then take this approximation and update the parameters of the generator distribution in the direction of the gradient of the critic. So in a sense we're just approximating a loss function and then we tell the generator in what direction is best to go. so a critic is a very good name for this, but calling it an adversarial network implies that the generator and the critic are at odds. Any ideas why this should still be nicknamed an adversarial network?

Comment: #1 we don’t change nicknames, #2 adversarial networks are adversarial because the avoidance of adversity is the path of least resistance, #3 you didn’t propose your own nickname.

Answer (score 0):

The name "adversarial" does not come from this paper, it comes from the GAN itself, this paper is merely an incremental work on top (and thus is not renaming anything). The reason why the "original" GAN is called **Generative Adversarial Network** is because it is trained in a form of a **two-player, competitive game**, where a generator task is to fool discriminator, and discriminators task is to well, not be fooled. This is the "at odds" part. And it is indeed critical to the whole system, vast majority of problems of GANs, that spawned hundreds of papers (like the one above) comes from the fact that greedy optimization of 2 player games has much more chaotic dynamics, and will not "just converge with small enough learning rate" that normal minimization of (smooth enough) loss function would. From math perspective, the subtle difference that makes things chaotic is that gradients that train discriminator **are not back-propagated** to the generator. Otherwise generator would be "helping" discriminator. Because of this stop gradient the emerging dynamics is no longer a gradient vector field of any loss, and instead it is a dynamical system emerging from simultaneous minimization of 2 functions (also called 2 player games).